# Turtlebot on Gazebo not operatable

Tags: gazebo, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please forgive this poorly formatted question, but `Turtlebot` on `Gazebo` is not operational. It used to be (in my experience at least October 10) working using turtlebot_teleop (which still publishes topic `turtlebot_node/cmd_vel` with certain values now). So I'm wondering there might have been update on `turtlebot` / `gazebo` side that could be causing this. I'm trying to use the packages that I haven't modified. Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.

Environment: Ubuntu 11.04/10.10, ROS `electric`

How to reproduce:

```
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_empty_world.launch
roslaunch turtlebot_teleop keyboard_teleop.launch
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11756/turtlebot-on-gazebo-not-operatable/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2011-11-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

yes this is a bug.. it's is ticketed here: https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/trac/ticket/87
I am working on getting things functional again and adding unit tests...

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2011-11-04**:
Thanks a lot!

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-11-03**:
Yes I'll  send an email out to TB users

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2011-11-03**:
@mwise_wg always appreciate you guys' hard work! Do you think you announce somewhere once the updated resource gets available?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just writing to confirm this bug (on Electric).

How to reproduce:

```
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_empty_world.launch
rosrun turtlebot_teleop turtlebot_teleop_key
```

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-11-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2011-11-01**:
I mean I experience the same phenomenon (simulated turtlebot doesn't react when running above commands). Doesn't work now (turtlebot_simulator 0.1.13), used to work a few weeks ago.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2011-11-01**:
@Martin Günther thanks, do you mean you also experience similar/same phenom? If so do you start seeing it recently or from before? Just asking for giving more info for developers.